# Repercussions of using <form action="." method="POST">

Tags: html, action, forms

Let's say I have a form that `POST`s to the same URL that generated the form. Let's also say that the URL is `somedomain.com/contractor/1/1/add-workers` and it's *really* important that the URL remain unchanged during the lifetime of the form.

So I set the form's action="." as the form is meant to POST to the same URL.

Under what circumstances can this leave my action attribute vulnerable to manipulation **/** fiddling by users? Let's say the user manually changes `somedomain.com/contractor/1/1/add-workers` in the address bar to `somedomain.com/contractor/1/2/add-workers` before POSTing the form, I think that has no repercussions, but what other circumstances should I keep in mind where the action attribute can be affected (unintentionally) by the user?

Comment: The user activating their browser's developer tools and changing the `action` to whatever they like? Or simply POSTing a custom request to the server by using any other external tool? You cannot prevent this. If there are security repercussions then you have to be able to solve them purely on the server.

Comment: anyone can do this or its login based?

Comment: Changing the URL in the address bar without hitting return won't have an effect. As @Jon has said though, you can't prevent them from opening up their developer tools and changing the `action` attribute manually.

Comment: Yes, that is impossible to prevent I guess. @Ark - it's login based.

Comment: @chefsmart you can check the user and compare to a permission-table

Comment: Just thinking aloud - Maybe I should send the URL where the form originates as a salted cipher within the form and then re-check the cipher when the form is posted to see if the action attribute has been fiddled with?